# Unable to set solution file with multiple projects as Hudson job for Subversion

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, build, hudson

I have a solution which has five projects , the first project is web project which references other fours projects dlls as project reference.I am trying to setup hudson job to build the solution , but it is unable to find the references for the projects.

RepositoryUrl i gave as below

http://svn.test.com/repos/solutions/MySolutions.

I have test.sln under this in the subversion.

MSBuildFile: test.sln.

When i run this hudson job it throws the following error.

```
..\..\libraries\mylibraries\Test.Common.Logging\Test.Common.Logging.csproj : Solution file warning MSB4122: Scanning project dependencies for project "..\..\libraries\Mylibraries\Test.Common.Logging\Test.Common.Logging.csproj" failed. The project file "F:\CIBuild\HudsonWorkspace\jobs\mytest.NET-PostCommit\workspace\solutionsdir\..\..\libraries\corelibraries\Test.Common.Logging\Test.Common.Logging.csproj" was not found.
```

any type of guidence will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally fix the problem.

I have to use the Custom Workspace while configuring hudson to specify the complete code base.

Anway thanks.